Hyperledger fabric documentation
What is best version of the official documentation of hyperledger fabric?
There is so many release version. Which version works smoother?
I'm trying the 2.5 release version. But I am getting some errors. My channels couldn’t build up properly.

You should probably use the version of the Hyperledger Fabric documentation that matches the version of Hyperledger Fabric that you are running. For example, if you are using Hyperledger Fabric v2.5, the version of the documentation to use is:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/
The version of the documentation marked latest matches the content of the Fabric source code repository's default (main) branch. At the time of writing, this is the version of the documentation you should use if you are using the Fabric v3.0 beta. Once a full Fabric v3.0 release is published, I would expect an accompanying release-3.0 version of the official documentation to appear.
If you haven't yet chosen a version of Hyperledger Fabric that you want to work with, I would recommend using the latest long-term support (LTS) release. At the time of writing, this is Fabric v2.5. See above for the link to the corresponding v2.5 documentation. This is the version you will get by default when running the Fabric install script.
Since a new Fabric Gateway client API for building client applications was introduced with Fabric v2.4, if you are starting now, I would not recommend using earlier Fabric versions. v2.5 is the only currently supported Fabric release, and uses the newer client application API, which is the only client application API compatible with the Byzantine Fault Tolerant (BFT) ordering service in Fabric v3.0.
A final note on the accompanying fabric-samples repository: as mentioned in the repository README, the default (main) branch contains samples for the latest Fabric release, and uses the current smart contract and client application APIs. At the time of writing this is Fabric v2.5 (and v3.0-beta). For older Fabric releases, refer to the matching samples repository branch. For example, if working with Fabric v2.2, refer to the fabric-samples/release-2.2 branch.
If you are having difficulty setting up a Fabric network, I suggest following through the getting started documentation with the provided samples before trying to build your own custom network.
